# How to get rid squared border around image?

Tags: html, css, image, angular

I have this image with a rounded shape, but how do I get rid of the square square edges/border?

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="picture">
<input type='file' id="input">
<img [src]="url" id="Image">
<label for="uploadinput" id="uploadlabel">Upload Picture</label>
```

CSS

```
#Image {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg');
  border-radius: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 240px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  border-radius: none; }
```

Comment: there is no border. you can check in jsfiddle also

Comment: There is no border for the image. It must be #picture that has border.

Comment: I have this  #profilepicture {
    outline: none;
    border:none;

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thin border that appears when there is no src is because chrome is showing that in fact no image exists in the space that you defined.  (Thanks to @Patrick Mlr for pointing it out.)

```css
#Image {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg');
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-size: 240px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  padding: 100px;
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: none; }
```

```html
<div id="picture">
<input type='file' id="input">
<img [src]="url" id="Image">
<label for="uploadinput" id="uploadlabel">Upload Picture</label>
```

Comment: It is strange because i have border in mine..

Comment: @vDog Do you use Chrome?

Comment: Yes i do use Chrome

Comment: @vDog See my answer here then: [remove the thin line in header images in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784368/remove-the-thin-line-in-header-images-in-bootstrap/39784555#39784555)

Comment: Oh i can see, when i use Microsoft Edge i have no border

Comment: #vdog can you please check if the current solution works for you

Comment: It works now, I removed the src attribute and it works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: But now i cannot upload any pictures

Comment: Are you unable to upload or are you unable to click on the input file button

Comment: I am unable to upload. I can click on the input file button and choose an image, but the image does not change.

Comment: Oh. I guess that is because you removed the src attribute. Can you keep it and just modify the width height and padding values like I have done in the snippet

Comment: I have tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/rabapre9/ but it does not seem to work

Comment: Oh. I see. That should be entirely different question now. Can you please create another question and tag it with typescript and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the color you can change the border width

```
{ border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(160,160,255); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the border on `#picture`:

```
#picture{
   border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Image {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg');
  border-radius: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 240px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none;
  border:0;
  border-radius: none;
}
```